# PHP - Remove Image Tag And Replace With Alt

Tags: php, regex, string

If I have a string like so:

```
Hi this is a photo of me <img src='myself.jpg' alt='pic of me' />. Another pic of me <img src='abc.jpg'/>
```

How can I turn that into:

```
Hi this is a photo of me (myself). Another pic of me (image)
```

Basically I want to remove all images from a string and replace them with their alt tag if it had one. If it doesn't it should say just 'image'.

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Best would be to use an HTML DOM parser library.

Comment: Javascript would be good but in this case I need it for php.

Comment: Don't understand that comment. There are HTML parsers for PHP.

Comment: Oh thought you meant dom as in javascript wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a [DOM parser](http://php.net/dom) instead of regex. Here's how:

- Load the HTML string using [`loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)
- Use [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to get all the images
- Loop through them and check if the image has an `alt` attribute.

  - If the image has an `alt` attribute, set the value of `$replacement` variable as the `alt` attribute.
  - If the image doesn't have an `alt` attribute, set the `$replacement` to `(image)`.
- Use [`replaceChild()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) to replace the node with the newly created text node:

Code:

```
$html = <<<HTML
Hi this is a photo of me <img src='myself.jpg' alt='pic of me' /> 
another pic of me <img src='abc.jpg'/> 
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$i = $images->length - 1;

while ($i > -1) { 
    $node = $images->item($i); 

    if ($node->hasAttribute('alt')) {
        $replacement = '('.$node->getAttribute('alt').')';
    }
    else {
        $replacement = '(image)';
    } 

    $text = $dom->createTextNode($replacement."\n");
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($text, $node);

    $i--; 
} 

echo strip_tags($dom->saveHTML());
```

Output:

```
Hi this is a photo of me (pic of me)
another pic of me (image)
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/79670)

Comment: Is this faster then using regex?

Comment: Regular expressions will likely be faster. But does it matter which is faster if one gives you incorrect results?

Comment: Ok but with your example what does it do if there is no alt attribute on the image?

Comment: @Nuvolari: If there is no `alt` attribute, it will *now* simply display the rest of the text. You can test it out yourself, btw.

Comment: Ok how can I do it so that if there is no alt it displays: '(image)' instead ?

Comment: $html = <<<HTML
Hi this is a photo of me <img src='myself.jpg' alt='pic of me' /> another pic of me <img src='abc.jpg'/>
HTML; If I use this it only replaces the first image tag and not the one without the alt

Comment: @Nuvolari: Ah, there was a slight mistake. Updated the answer again with a new demo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
preg_match_all('/\<img[^\>]*\>/', $yourString, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $match)
{
   $replacement = 'image';

   if (preg_match('/alt=\'([^\']+)\'/', $match, $matches2))
      $replacement = $matches2[1];

   $yourString = str_replace($match, '('.$replacement.')', $yourString);
}
```

What it does: finds all img tags and gets them to $matches array. Cycles through them and looks for alt value. If one exists the IMG tag is replaces with (ALT VALUE) otherwise it's replaced with (image).

Comment: If the image doesn't contain an alt tag, what will this display?

Comment: There's not gonna be a match so you won't replace anything

Comment: Use `$matches[1] ? $matches[1] : 'image'`

Comment: And make the `alt=...` stuff optional in the regexp so the `if` succeeds.

Comment: I guess first of all you have to define what the algorithm should do in that case. I'm sure we'll come up with something here :)